# Packaging only a certain subset of built files

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I'm attempting to package `libmp3lame` and `libmp3lame-devel` much the same way that Debian packages it: they have `libmp3lame` as a package providing the `libmp3lame.so` shared library, `libmp3lame-dev` providing header files and documentation, and `lame` depending on `libmp3lame` providing the actual binary.

Here is my spec file, `libmp3lame.spec`:

```
Summary: Shared libraries for LAME.
Name: libmp3lame
Version: 3.99.5
Release: 1
License: LGPL
Vendor: The LAME Project
Packager: Naftuli Tzvi Kay <--->
URL: http://www.mp3dev.org
Group: Applications/Multimedia
Source: lame-%{version}.tar.gz
BuildRequires: gcc => 3.0.1, /usr/bin/find, ncurses-devel, nasm

%description
Shared libraries for LAME.

%package devel
Summary: Shared libraries for LAME (development files).
Group: Development/Libraries
Requires: %{name} = %{version}

%description devel
Shared libraries for LAME (development files).

%prep
%setup -n lame-%{version}

%build

# Vorbis makes the build fail for now. . .
rm -f config.cache

# configuration swiped from debian
%configure \
    --enable-nasm \
    --disable-rpath \
    --enable-dynamic-frontends \
    --enable-expopt=full \
    --enable-nasm \
    --with-fileio=lame
%{__make} %{?_smp_mflags} test CFLAGS="%{optflags}"

%install

%makeinstall
%{__ln_s} -f lame/lame.h %{buildroot}%{_includedir}/lame.h
### make install really shouldn't install these
# %{__rm} -rf %{buildroot}%{_docdir}/lame/

%post
/sbin/ldconfig

%postun
/sbin/ldconfig

%clean
%{__rm} -rf %{buildroot}

%files
%defattr (-,root,root)
%{_libdir}/libmp3lame.so.*
%{_libdir}/libmp3lame.so

%files devel
%defattr (-, root, root)
%doc API HACKING STYLEGUIDE
%{_includedir}/*

%changelog

* Mon Jan 11 2016 Naftuli Tzvi Kay <---> - 3.99.5-1
- Repackaged for reasons.
```

I'm seeing the following build errors:

```
RPM build errors:
    Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
   /usr/bin/lame
   /usr/lib64/libmp3lame.a
   /usr/lib64/libmp3lame.la
   /usr/share/doc/lame/html/about.html
   /usr/share/doc/lame/html/abr.html
   /usr/share/doc/lame/html/cbr.html
   /usr/share/doc/lame/html/contact.html
   /usr/share/doc/lame/html/contributors.html
   /usr/share/doc/lame/html/detailed.html
   /usr/share/doc/lame/html/history.html
   /usr/share/doc/lame/html/index.html
   /usr/share/doc/lame/html/introduction.html
   /usr/share/doc/lame/html/links.html
   /usr/share/doc/lame/html/list.html
   /usr/share/doc/lame/html/ms_stereo.html
   /usr/share/doc/lame/html/usage.html
   /usr/share/doc/lame/html/vbr.html
   /usr/share/man/man1/lame.1.gz
```

I'm trying to only include the files I need in the final RPMs, but it seems to still complain about this.

Comment: because they're not being included in any %files section

Comment: %{_libdir}/libmp3lame.so belongs in the devel package.  just sayin' :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Built files that get created with `make install` during the `%makeinstall` phase need to be explicitly included or excluded.

I was able to work around this by running manual `rm` commands after `%makeinstall`, but there appears to be another workaround in the `%files` section using `%exclude` clauses:

```
%files
%defattr (-,root,root)
%{_libdir}/libmp3lame.so.*
%{_libdir}/libmp3lame.so
%exclude %{_bindir}/lame
%exclude %{_libdir}/libmp3lame.a
%exclude %{_libdir}/libmp3lame.la
```